# How to clear the current MediaPlayer playlist?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller

I need to clear current playlist, when a user choose another playlist. When I choose another playlist, method onChildrenLoaded() called and there is some code, but it's problem, because this method add items to current playlist, but not clear it. I think, I need to add method "clearPlaylist()" to my MediaControllerCompat, but this class is declarated as final. How I can solve my problem?

```
        for (mediaItem in children) {
            mediaController.addQueueItem(mediaItem.description)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For API level >=26.1.0:**

```
mediaController.removeQueueItem(MediaDescriptionCompat)
```

**For API level <26.1.0:**

```
mediaController.removeQueueItemAt(int index)
```

For further information you can also refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat).

\e:

```js
private void clearPlaylist(int sizeOfPlaylist) {

 for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfPlaylist; i++) {
  mediaController.removeQueueItemAt(i);
 }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this method delete only one QueueItem, I need to delete all items

Comment: simply iterate over the whole queue. I still dont know which API level you are using but i edited my answer and provided a method.